# I only have emoticons and not text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a generator of random letters, but instead of letters I only have emoticons. Here is the code.

```
import random
from random import randint

#random number of characters
sym=random.randint(100,500)
num=0
bn=[]

while num < sym :
    rb=random.randint(0,1)
    bn.append(rb)
    num+=1 
print(bn) #for check

bn=str(''.join(map(str, bn)))



def decode(lst):
    txt= ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(int(x,2)), lst))
    print("txt=",txt)


decode(bn)
```

The code should be letters or even numbers, but don't smile! I tried all the ways I could think of, but the result is the same

Comment: Of course.  Every character you get will only be ASCII 0 or ASCII 1, both of which are unprintable control characters.  Instead of picking numbers through binary, just create a string with all the letters you want to use (upper/lower/numbers?), then use `random.choice` to pick one at a time.

Comment: You generate random numbers from 0 to.... 1. You're going to get ASCII values 0 and 1, which correspond to the characters "Null" and "Start of Heading". On some old systems, these control characters print as emoticons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how to use `random.choice` to pick a random string.

```
import random

sym=random.randint(100,500)
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890"

bn=[]
for _ in range(sym):
    bn.append(random.choice(alphabet))
bn = ''.join(bn)
print(bn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I didn't know about ASCII 0 and ASCII 1 for binary code (I'm just a beginner)

Comment: You need to understand the ASCII code if you're working with characters.  The digit "0" has ASCII code 48.  The capital letters are ASCII codes 65 to 90.  The lower case letters are 97 to 122.  Anything below 32 is "not printable", like carriage return (15) and line feed (12).